# Searching with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to search through a model for all records with a certain tag.

Sample output we are trying to search:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :1 > Question.last.tags
=> [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "preferences">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 13, name: "travel">]
```

So, `Question` has `tags` such as preferences and travel. I tried:

```
@tags = @questions.where("tags LIKE ?", "%#{params[:tags]}%")
=> []

@tags = @questions.where("tag LIKE ?", "%#{params[:tags]}%")
=> []

@tags = @questions.where("tag_list LIKE ?", "%#{params[:tags]}%")
=> BadFieldError: Unknown column 'tag_list'
```

How can I return the top record when `params[:tags]` is, for example, "refere" or "ences"?

#### Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many ...
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

### Second Try

I just created a custom controller action to try to change the query as per **@Nash**'s suggestion. How can I correct it?

```
def autocomplete_question_tags
  @tags = Question.tagged_with("%#{params[:term]}", :any => true)
  respond_to do |format|
      format.json
  end
end
```

Upon entering 'travel' into the form:

`Started GET "/answers/autocomplete_question_tags?term=travel" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-16 20:37:34 -0400

  Processing by AnswersController#autocomplete_question_tags as JSON

  Parameters: {"term"=>"travel"}

{"term"=>"travel", "action"=>"autocomplete_question_tags", "controller"=>"answers"}

  SQL (1.8ms)  SHOW TABLES

  SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM (SELECT 1 FROM 'questions' WHERE (questions.id IN (SELECT taggings.taggable_id FROM taggings JOIN tags ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id AND (tags.name LIKE '%travel') WHERE taggings.taggable_type = 'Question'))) AS subquery

logger.debug: 1 result in query

Completed   in 114ms`

`ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template answers/autocomplete_question_tags with   {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:json], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/san/Documents/san/apl/app/views",

  app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:36:in 'autocomplete_question_tags'`

`Rendered /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)`

Comment: could you show us your Question model? And why do you have tags or tag column in your questions table?

Comment: @nash - Sure, I'll post the question model. I have tags in the questions table because I want questions to be tagged, as per the example at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on, where the User table is tagged on three fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could allow your parameter to search any part of a tag instead.

```
Question.tagged_with("%#{params[:tags]}%", :any => true)
```

Comment: the controller action (and therefore the query) isn't specified by me - it's generated automatically by acts_as_taggable_on. How can I modify the query it automatically generates to what you suggested?

Comment: At first, you can use `acts_as_taggable` instead of `acts_as_taggable_on :tags`. And what do yo mean generated automatically by `acts_as_taggable_on`? As I know, `acts_as_taggable_on` can generate migration only. Secondly, you should use `"%#{params[:term]}#"` instead of `"%#{params[:term]}"` if you want to find something like "refere". And in your controller pass your found questions into view `format.json => @tags`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer no longer works.

The current solution is:

```
Question.tagged_with(params[:tags], wild: true, any: true)
```

Comment: Checked with version 4.0.0 of ActsAsTaggableOn: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects